# Iteration through dictionary and graphing

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach, iterator

I have a dictionary populated with a value that is a class containing an int and a double. Im trying to graph two of the int value against the double as x and y points on a graph by iterating through the dictionary. This is what it looks like:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, Class> Pair in MyClass)
{
chart1.Series["series1"].Points.AddXY(Pair.Value.intA, Pair.Value.doubleB);
}
```

my problem is that the only x-y pair being charted is the very last class contained in the dictionary, when the dictionary has over 100 lines. I have no idea why this is happening and am at a loss. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That suggests you've got multiple references to a single instance of `Class`. Please show how you're populating the dictionary. You should also consider just using `foreach (var value in MyClass.Values)`

Comment: What graph control are you using? Seems odd that it works until you have over 100 Points.

Comment: @TyCobb I don't think they are saying it works when they have less than 100 points; I think they are saying that it renders the value from the last item in the dictionary for every point.

Comment: @AllanElder Got it. I can see how it could be read both ways. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you declaring the instance of Class in MyClass?

if you do

```
var item = new Class();
var items = new Dictionary<int, Class>();
for(var x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{
    item.Value = x;
    items[x] = item;
}
```

Every KeyValuePair in the dictionary is referring to the same instance of Class.

if you do

```
var items = new Dictionary<int, Class>();
for(var x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{
    var item = new Class();
    item.Value = x;
    items[x] = item;
}
```

Every KeyValuePair in the dictionary is referring to a new instance of Class.